# As it happened, I removed ruby and rubygems. And now I can not restore

Tags: ruby, rubygems, centos, reinstall

I have: CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

As it happened, I removed ruby:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby
rm -Rf /usr/lib/ruby
```

I tried to update, remove, reinstall ruby and rubygems, but unfortunately does not work :(
But I have the following errors:

```
[root@localhost /]# gem --version
:1:in 'require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
        from :1:in ''
```

Maybe you have some ideas?

Comment: Why did you delete it in the first place? Use `yum install` to reinstall Ruby and RubyGems. And stop running as the root user on your system until you know what you are doing. Instead, log in as a normal user and carefully use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you try [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).

Since you are using CentOS [this guide](https://gist.github.com/jpfuentes2/2002954) may help you.

Comment: @IgorFeoktistov, have you installed/specified ruby version? If yes when I don't know how to help you, sorry.